# Issues connecting to internet through phone hotspot

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, android

I'm having a very strange issue with my Windows 10 computer and I really cannot describe it in one word, so here's what's happening:

I have my cell phone's Internet, and Home's Internet.

I usually connect my laptop through the cell phone's Internet, and connect to site1.com. my browsers all of them show me site not found as if DNS is wrong or I dunno what to call it; the real word example is that I moved one of my domains to a new hosting through updating nameservers, the site broke and stayed broke for sometime, I checked the site address from my phone's browser and IT WORKED!, the very same internet.

What's making it more strange is that if I from my Windows connect to my home's internet the site WORKS again.

It's only THIS PHONE INTERNET + MY LAPTOP. so phone's internet + phone's browser works, and laptop's internet through home's internet again works, only windows + my phones internet does not work but works on the very same internet if i check from the phone's BROWSER! It's FRUSTRATING and i really can't find the keywords to look it up online and find a solution and it IS strange !! it's like windows + phone's internet does not rechecked the DNS of the sites i'm vising in case they were changed. I really do NOT get it!

**UPDATE 1:** I tested the site on Kali through VMWARE, so it's kind of a different OS using my network adapters, SAME ISSUE. site is not opening.

I tested ping on my Windows for the site it gave me a different IP than the correct IP. a reminder, the same internet on phone's browser is working.

**UPDATE 2:** close to solution, I tried to let another device connect to my android device, and the same issue happened, the site1 is not opening on their devices, so issue is from my android device internet sharing.

Comment: Can you visit other websites through the phone's internet by using windows?

Comment: yes i did test almost everything, check the update.

Comment: Is the ip address of the DNS server different on Kali than on your phone?

Comment: the network type on vmware is NAT

Comment: Are you allowed to use your phone's internet connection to do tethering? Phone operators can technically detect if the traffic comes from your phone or from a computer connected through your phone's internet connection.

Comment: @Swisstone i posted a new update, i tried to let other device to connect to my phone's internet, and the same issue happening on my windows is happening, not connecting to site1, which recently changed the nameserver so it's not really updating the dns of things and ONLY through internet sharing, since my android's browser things are normal, only through sharing windows/or other android devices recently changed sites won't open

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by resetting an Android device and not a device within the scope of Superuser

Comment: Personally, I would leave this open unless it's a duplicate. The issue was first visible on the PC, and its an issue others are likely to experience. Leaving this Q and A will point them to the correct solution: reset the device they are hotspotting through.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Resetting my Android Device.